# Raw Read Error Rate for Intel SSDs

Tags: ssd, intel, smart

I've provisioned a few servers with a bunch of Intel S3610's and I'm a bit concerned about the "Raw Read Error Rate" values. The tools shows all drives as healthy and there are no other errors as shown as full SMART data pasted below for one drive.

Does these values mean anything?

```
:~# isdct show -smart 01 -intelssd

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3163710634
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3158519941
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3164737702
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3152729088
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3161462193
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3155225677
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3159076215
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130

- SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN -


- 01 -

Action : Pass
Description : Raw Read Error Rate
ID : 01
Normalized : 130
Raw : 3156418161
Status : 14
Threshold : 39
Worst : 130
```

---

```
"SMART Attributes BTHXXXXXXXX800NGN":
{
    "01":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Raw Read Error Rate",
        "ID":"01",
        "Normalized":130,
        "Raw":1925235567,
        "Status":14,
        "Threshold":39,
        "Worst":130
    },
    "05":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Re-allocated Sector Count",
        "ID":"05",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":51,
        "Threshold":1,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "09":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Power-On Hours Count",
        "ID":"09",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":353,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "0C":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Power Cycle Count",
        "ID":"0C",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":30,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "0D":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"ECC Rate",
        "ID":"0D",
        "Normalized":119,
        "Raw":719184773999,
        "Status":30,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "B3":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Used reserved block count (total)",
        "ID":"B3",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":51,
        "Threshold":10,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "B4":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Unused Reserved block count (total)",
        "ID":"B4",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":17930,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "B5":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Program fail count (total)",
        "ID":"B5",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":58,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "B6":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Erase fail count (total)",
        "ID":"B6",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":58,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "B8":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"End-to-End Error Detection Count",
        "ID":"B8",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "C2":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Drive Temperature",
        "ID":"C2",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":27,
        "Status":34,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "C3":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Uncorrectable Error Count",
        "ID":"C3",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "C6":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Offline Scan Uncorrectable LBA Count",
        "ID":"C6",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":16,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "C7":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"CRC Error Count",
        "ID":"C7",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":62,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "C9":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Volatile Memory Backup Source Failure",
        "ID":"C9",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":55857979570,
        "Status":51,
        "Threshold":10,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "CA":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Exception Mode Status (Read-only mode)",
        "ID":"CA",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":39,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "E2":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Timed Workload - Media Wear",
        "ID":"E2",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":102400,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "E3":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Timed Workload - Host Read/Write Ratio",
        "ID":"E3",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "E4":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Timed Workload Timer",
        "ID":"E4",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":3783287515,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "E9":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Number of write count",
        "ID":"E9",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":85593,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    },
    "F5":
    {
        "Action":"Pass",
        "Description":"Percent Drive Life Remaining",
        "ID":"F5",
        "Normalized":100,
        "Raw":0,
        "Status":50,
        "Threshold":0,
        "Worst":100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Raw Read Error Rate` field is often formatted in a proprietary, undisclosed manner, or entirely used to codify other information. In short, don't pay attention to the raw value by itself.

Rather, carefully examine the `normalized`, `threshold` and `worse` data: from them, we can see that your disk are in good health.

Other important fields are the `Uncorrectable Error Count`, `Re-allocated Sector Count` and `Percent Drive Life Remaining`: their raw values are generally codified in absolute values, and they show your drives as healthy.